# Configuring auto realm discovery in Azure AD B2C

Tags: openid, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've been trying to configure auto realm discovery for an Azure AD application being accessed through Azure AD B2C.

The current login flow I'm looking at is for a user at TestCompany (with an email address ending in `@testcompany.com`) who wants to login via B2C to the TestCompany Azure AD. B2C then forwards the user and sends the relevant tokens to the Azure AD instance, which does realm discovery once the user inputs the aforementioned email address, and refreshes the login page with the already-configured TestCompany-branded Azure AD sign-in page.

This is working correctly at present, but I wish for users who login to the TestCompany Azure AD to have the Azure AD login page be already branded once B2C forwards them through. While looking for an answer to this problem, I found this [Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/02/11/using-azure-ad-to-land-users-on-their-custom-login-page-from-within-your-app/) that mentions that for web applications that are using the Open ID Connect protocol that the following query string parameter `&domain_hint=testcompany.com` simply needs to be added to the sign-in URL.

By simply taking the URL that populates the address field when the user goes into the TestCompany Azure AD login flow and adding the query string parameter into it I can confirm this is the functionality I want, but I simply don't know where to add this query string. The registered app for the Azure AD instance in the Azure portal has fields to change the *Home page URL* and to add *Reply URLs*. I can't see anything in the Azure B2C settings that seems relevant.

I'm currently using custom policies, and have the Azure AD provider created as a ClaimsProvider using the OpenIdConnect protocol in the TrustFrameworkBase.

I feel like I might just be missing something really obvious, but any help would be appreciated. If you require any more information I will edit this question accordingly.